# My Rails Application doesn't update the localized strings in production mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, internationalization

I have a standard Rails application running with the I18n support. I have extensive caching running for this app. I edited a few strings and confirmed it worked locally. I also confirmed I have the right strings on the file for the live site. Still for some weird reason I do not see these changes for my live site even though I have not fragment cached anything here.

Any ideas what is going on?

Answer (score 2):

Another one with the same problem as me :)

I ended up with this solution:
http://szeryf.wordpress.com/2008/02/02/multilingual-page-caching-in-ruby-on-rails/

I couldn't change the structure to include the language identifier in the URL as suggested here:
http://groups.google.com/group/rubyonrails-talk/browse_thread/thread/341bba9357bfc608

Depending on your structure and how fare you are down development, choose either one. However, it's probably easier if you have the cache either as part of your domain or your url.

I hope multilingual caching will be improved in future rails versions.

Comment: I should have closed out this question. I always run full caching locally why it was surprising to me. The answer turned out to be that I used rsync to deploy to production and I had a left-over file that did not get deleted. Very silly I know.